# Error accessing Web Services from WSDL

Tags: java, soap, netbeans, wsdl, java-ee-7

After hours of working I have found a way to create a SOAP client that performs calls to web servers. I did two tests on public web servers and everything went okay. When I did a project with another server I got an error:

> Web Service Client can not be created by JAXWS:wsimport utility.
>   Reason: 'Any' Property already defined. Use `<jaxb:property>` to
>   resolve this conflict

I am using Java EE 7 and Netbeans to create the web service client.

The problem maybe is that this web server requires a username and password to download the WSDL file.

How I can resolve this, and how can I enter a username and password to request the WSDL file?

---

EDIT:
The problem is not related to SSL, beacause I can access to WSDL from browser.

Comment: Did you try 3'rd party libraries to create client stub? e.g. CXF or Axis. Try to check that WSDL with [SoapUI](https://www.soapui.org/)

Comment: @Denis Kurochkin WIth SoapUI works.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [error while consuming a .Net web service from a WSDL in NetBeans](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9189236/error-while-consuming-a-net-web-service-from-a-wsdl-in-netbeans)

Comment: Another possible solution - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/785945/problem-generating-java-soap-web-services-client-with-jdk-tool-wsimport-from-a-w?rq=1